# np.concatenate a list of numpy.ndarray in new dimension?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list with numpy.ndarrays - each of shape `(33,1,8,45,3)`

Problem that when i concatenate the list using `a = np.concatenate(list)`
The output shape of a becomes

```
print a.shape 
(726,1,8,45,3)
```

instead of shape `(22,33,1,8,45,3)`.

How do I cleanly concatenate the list, without having to change the input.

Comment: How about `np.array(input_list)` or even `np.asarray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.array()` or `numpy.stack()`:

```
import numpy
a = [numpy.random.rand(33,1,8,45,3) for i in range(22)]

b = numpy.array(a)
b.shape    # (22, 33, 1, 8, 45, 3)

c = numpy.stack(a, axis=0)
c.shape    # (22, 33, 1, 8, 45, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

> Join a sequence of arrays along an **existing axis**.

[`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack):

> Stack a sequence of arrays along a **new axis**.

```
a = np.ones((3, 4))
b = np.stack([a, a])
print(b.shape)  # (2, 3, 4)
```